# Calendar / scheduler - resources on horizontal (columns) and days with hours on vertical

Tags: angular, calendar, scheduler

I would like to prepare calendar with resources on horizontal (columns) and days with hours on vertical. I mean to have week or month view (or infinite?) on vertical line. For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObViL.png)

Is there any predefined calendar for realize that (like fullcalendar)?
I need solution for Angular.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fullcalendar utility for Angular.

I have used it for an Enterprise project previously and can vouch for its performance and versatility.

You follow the below link to integrate it into your Angular project.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Comment: There is no solution from fullcalendar which I have described.